# Rewrite '/it/public/' to '/it/'

Tags: .htaccess, laravel

I've looked everywhere for an htaccess rule that can rewrite a url from:

`customer.com/it/public/` to `customer.com/it/`

My folder structure is like this:

```
/customer.com
   .htaccess
    |-- it
        |-- .htaccess
        |-- public
        |   |-- .htaccess
```

Inside the root of the website, is a Codeigniter app, and inside the `IT` folder, there is a Laravel app.

This is my current HTACCESS in the root of my website (rewrites the codeigniter index.php):

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine on
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule .* index.php/$0 [PT,L]
</IfModule>
```

These are the rules in my HTACCESS file in the root of the `IT` folder (supposed to rewrite laravel public folder):

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine on
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^public/
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /public/$1 [L]
</IfModule>
```

And these are the rules inside the HTACCESS file in the Public folder (rewrites the index.php inside the public folder):

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    <IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
        Options -MultiViews
    </IfModule>

    RewriteEngine On

    # Redirect Trailing Slashes...
    RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ /$1 [L,R=301]

    # Handle Front Controller...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

Portion of the debug:

```
DOCUMENT_ROOT   C:/xampp/htdocs
REQUEST_SCHEME  http
CONTEXT_PREFIX  
CONTEXT_DOCUMENT_ROOT   C:/xampp/htdocs
SERVER_ADMIN    postmaster@localhost
SCRIPT_FILENAME C:/xampp/htdocs/it/public/index.php
REMOTE_PORT 44461
REDIRECT_URL    /it/
GATEWAY_INTERFACE   CGI/1.1
SERVER_PROTOCOL HTTP/1.1
REQUEST_METHOD  GET
QUERY_STRING    
REQUEST_URI /it/
SCRIPT_NAME /it/public/index.php
PHP_SELF    /it/public/index.php
REQUEST_TIME_FLOAT  1395338241.106
REQUEST_TIME    1395338241
```

Answer (score 0):

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /public/$1 [L]
```

This line produces an absolute substitution, so mod_rewrite does not add back the directory prefix ("it" in this case). Try to replace that rule with the following:

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ public/$1 [L] #relative substitution
```

or with this:

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /it/public/$1 [L] #absolute substitution including dir prefix
```

PS: You don't really want to rewrite "/it/public/" to "/it/", rather the opposite.

EDIT: Also, remove the "redirect trailing slashes" rule.

Comment: This definitely did something. Instead of a codeigniter 404 page I get the laravel 404 error page when I try `customer.com/it`. Are there paths I need to configure in laravel to allow it to run in a subfolder?

Comment: If /bootstrap/paths.php is properly configured, it should work. Could you post the debug message?

Comment: I haven't changed them, their the stock paths. But it doesn't seem like I need to since they just look for the directory above which is indeed correct. This is what's returned for `__DIR__` : `C:\xampp\htdocs\it\bootstrap`, which is correct. I'll see what I can do